# How to add url parameters to flask-dance "redirect_to" variable?

Tags: flask, flask-dance

I am using the flask-dance library to handle custom OAuth, here's a code sample:

```
oh = OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint(
    "oh", __name__,
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    authorization_url="",
    token_url="",
    redirect_uri="",
    scope=[""],
    redirect_to='/oauth-redirect'
)
```

I want to specify a URL parameter so that when the token is granted and the 3rd party website redirects back to my website, it knows where it came from. Like:

```
localhost:5010/oauth-redirect?id=oh
```

I know the `redirect_to` variable is a repurposed `url_for` via:

https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_dance.consumer.OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint

which accepts vars like: `url_for('page.route', foo="bar")` but how do I do something similar, be it passing data to the page or as a url parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the [`oauth_authorized` signal](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html#flask_dance.consumer.oauth_authorized), and return a response object. This response can redirect to whatever URL you want, and you can pass whatever data you want in the URL parameters.